# ${\left( \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\right)}^2 \le 2\int_{0}^{1} x{(f(x))}^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Let f be a non-decreasing, integrable function defined on [0, 1]. Show
that
$${\left( \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\right)}^2 \le 2\int_{0}^{1} x{(f(x))}^2$$

I tried using by parts , but it is of no help,

${\left( \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\right)}^2 \le\int_{0}^{1} {(f(x))}^2$

Any hints?

Comment: Do you know about the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: yes . it only gives upper bound,

Comment: $\displaystyle\mathrm{f}\left(x\right) \equiv x - 1\color{red}{ \implies} {1 \over 4} \leq {1 \over 6}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume first that $f$ is nonnegative.

Let $F(x)=\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\right)^{2}$, then
\begin{align*}
F'(x)=2\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dtf(x)\leq 2x(f(x))^{2},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
F(1)-F(0)=\int_{0}^{1}F'(x)dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}2x(f(x))^{2}dx.
\end{align*}